# How to scale a BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage, image-scaling

Following the javadocs, I have tried to scale a `BufferedImage` without success here is my code:

```
BufferedImage image = MatrixToImageWriter.getBufferedImage(encoded);
Graphics2D grph = image.createGraphics();
grph.scale(2.0, 2.0);
grph.dispose();
```

I can't understand why it is not working, any help?

Comment: An excelent tutorial: http://www.glyphic.com/transform/applet/1intro.html

Comment: As of this writing, the most popular answer is the wrong answer. It scales the image up, but it return an image of the same size, with 3/4 of the image missing. It's the answer given by trashgod. It's close, but it has a small bug.

Comment: Thanks, @MiguelMunoz. As we have more feedback I can change the answer.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

[`AffineTransformOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html) offers the additional flexibility of choosing the interpolation type.

```
BufferedImage before = getBufferedImage(encoded);
int w = before.getWidth();
int h = before.getHeight();
BufferedImage after = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.scale(2.0, 2.0);
AffineTransformOp scaleOp = 
   new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
after = scaleOp.filter(before, after);
```

The fragment shown illustrates [*resampling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling), not [*cropping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image)); this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46211880/230513) addresses the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage/46211880#comment79385871_4216635); some related examples are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=AffineTransformOp).

Comment: Is it really needed to allocate all the memory for `after`, when you have a statement like: `after = ...`?

Comment: @Martijn: It depends on which `ColorModel` you want in [`filter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html#filter%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImage%29). It's returning a reference, so there's no extra memory.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with a desired width and height instead of scale factor?

Comment: Yes, the scale parameters are just the ratios of new to old for _x_ and _y_, respectively; keep them equal to preserve the aspect ratio.

Comment: How fast is this? I need some fast calculations for computer vision.

Comment: @TomášZato: You may need to [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) a representative sample.

Comment: A tiny tweak, because 1 line is better than 2...
  AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(2.0, 2.0);

Comment: I haven't tried this code, but I'm not sure if it will work. You're creating a BufferedImage called "after" that has the same dimensions as the original. You may need to scale the dimensions for the new image. But, again, I'm not sure about this. scaleOp.filter() may take care of that for you.

Comment: I just tested it. As I suspected, `after` is the same size, and it's just the top left quarter of the original. The fix is to multiply w and h by the scale when creating `after`.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz  this code is pretty old, I haven't tested your answer, let me get more feedback then I can change the answer.

Comment: @ThiagoDiniz: The fragment is minimal, but correct; this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46211880/230513) illustrates resampling the result to optimize cropping.

Comment: This is gold!!!

Answer (score 40):

Unfortunately the performance of getScaledInstance() is very poor if not problematic.

The alternative approach is to create a new BufferedImage and and draw a scaled version of the original on the new one.

```
BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, original.getType());
Graphics2D g = resized.createGraphics();
g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g.drawImage(original, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, 0, 0, original.getWidth(),
    original.getHeight(), null);
g.dispose();
```

newWidth,newHeight indicate the new BufferedImage size and have to be properly calculated.
In case of factor scaling:

```
int newWidth = new Double(original.getWidth() * widthFactor).intValue();
int newHeight = new Double(original.getHeight() * heightFactor).intValue();
```

**EDIT**: Found the article illustrating the performance issue: [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983611)

Comment: I think getScaledInstance() is faster nowadays, at least if you have a decent graphics card, thanks to the optimized Java2D rendering pipeline.

Comment: FYI see **[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html)** other possible values for `RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION`

Comment: This helped me a lot without changing the library

Comment: One significant problem with this approach: it doesn't work if original.getType() == TYPE_CUSTOM, since you cannot construct a BufferedImage using that value.

Answer (score 15):

Using imgscalr – Java Image Scaling Library:

```
BufferedImage image =
     Scalr.resize(originalImage, Scalr.Method.BALANCED, newWidth, newHeight);
```

https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr

Comment: Agreed, this is the best solution and avoids all the problems with transparency, wrong translations, wrong colors, etc when using affinetransform and the various other methods.

Comment: Awesome! First solution I have seen on this thread that got me what I needed.

Comment: this solution worked for me. didn't even bother with the other ones.

Answer (score 13):

To scale an image, you need to create a new image and draw into it. One way is to use the `filter()` method of an `AffineTransferOp`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216635/230513). This allows you to choose the interpolation technique.

```
private static BufferedImage scale1(BufferedImage before, double scale) {
    int w = before.getWidth();
    int h = before.getHeight();
    // Create a new image of the proper size
    int w2 = (int) (w * scale);
    int h2 = (int) (h * scale);
    BufferedImage after = new BufferedImage(w2, h2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    AffineTransform scaleInstance = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale);
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp 
        = new AffineTransformOp(scaleInstance, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    scaleOp.filter(before, after);
    return after;
}
```

Another way is to simply draw the original image into the new image, using a scaling operation to do the scaling. This method is very similar, but it also illustrates how you can draw anything you want in the final image. (I put in a blank line where the two methods start to differ.)

```
private static BufferedImage scale2(BufferedImage before, double scale) {
    int w = before.getWidth();
    int h = before.getHeight();
    // Create a new image of the proper size
    int w2 = (int) (w * scale);
    int h2 = (int) (h * scale);
    BufferedImage after = new BufferedImage(w2, h2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    AffineTransform scaleInstance = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale);
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp 
        = new AffineTransformOp(scaleInstance, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) after.getGraphics();
    // Here, you may draw anything you want into the new image, but we're
    // drawing a scaled version of the original image.
    g2.drawImage(before, scaleOp, 0, 0);
    g2.dispose();
    return after;
}
```

**Addendum: Results**

To illustrate the differences, I compared the results of the five methods below. Here is what the results look like, scaled both up and down, along with performance data. (Performance varies from one run to the next, so take these numbers only as rough guidelines.) The top image is the original. I scale it double-size and half-size.

As you can see, `AffineTransformOp.filter()`, used in `scaleBilinear()`, is faster than the standard drawing method of `Graphics2D.drawImage()` in `scale2()`. Also BiCubic interpolation is the slowest, but gives the best results when expanding the image. (For performance, it should only be compared with `scaleBilinear()` and `scaleNearest().`) Bilinear seems to be better for shrinking the image, although it's a tough call. And NearestNeighbor is the fastest, with the worst results. Bilinear seems to be the best compromise between speed and quality. The `Image.getScaledInstance()`, called in the `questionable()` method, performed very poorly, and returned the same low quality as NearestNeighbor. (Performance numbers are only given for expanding the image.)

[image]

```
public static BufferedImage scaleBilinear(BufferedImage before, double scale) {
    final int interpolation = AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR;
    return scale(before, scale, interpolation);
}

public static BufferedImage scaleBicubic(BufferedImage before, double scale) {
    final int interpolation = AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BICUBIC;
    return scale(before, scale, interpolation);
}

public static BufferedImage scaleNearest(BufferedImage before, double scale) {
    final int interpolation = AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR;
    return scale(before, scale, interpolation);
}

@NotNull
private static 
BufferedImage scale(final BufferedImage before, final double scale, final int type) {
    int w = before.getWidth();
    int h = before.getHeight();
    int w2 = (int) (w * scale);
    int h2 = (int) (h * scale);
    BufferedImage after = new BufferedImage(w2, h2, before.getType());
    AffineTransform scaleInstance = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale);
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(scaleInstance, type);
    scaleOp.filter(before, after);
    return after;
}

/**
 * This is a more generic solution. It produces the same result, but it shows how you 
 * can draw anything you want into the newly created image. It's slower 
 * than scaleBilinear().
 * @param before The original image
 * @param scale The scale factor
 * @return A scaled version of the original image
 */
private static BufferedImage scale2(BufferedImage before, double scale) {
    int w = before.getWidth();
    int h = before.getHeight();
    // Create a new image of the proper size
    int w2 = (int) (w * scale);
    int h2 = (int) (h * scale);
    BufferedImage after = new BufferedImage(w2, h2, before.getType());
    AffineTransform scaleInstance = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale);
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp
            = new AffineTransformOp(scaleInstance, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) after.getGraphics();
    // Here, you may draw anything you want into the new image, but we're just drawing
    // a scaled version of the original image. This is slower than 
    // calling scaleOp.filter().
    g2.drawImage(before, scaleOp, 0, 0);
    g2.dispose();
    return after;
}

/**
 * I call this one "questionable" because it uses the questionable getScaledImage() 
 * method. This method is no longer favored because it's slow, as my tests confirm.
 * @param before The original image
 * @param scale The scale factor
 * @return The scaled image.
 */
private static Image questionable(final BufferedImage before, double scale) {
    int w2 = (int) (before.getWidth() * scale);
    int h2 = (int) (before.getHeight() * scale);
    return before.getScaledInstance(w2, h2, Image.SCALE_FAST);
}
```

Comment: Can you also recommend something that gives smooth results when scaling *down*? `getScaledInstance` with `Image.SCALE_SMOOTH` does but is incredibibly slow as everyone knows. Everything else I tried (including `AffineTransformOp` and drawing with a transformation applied with any combination of RenderingHints) gives me jagged edges.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to suggest something, but I have no idea if it will work well, or if it will be any faster. Try doing a two-stage scaling, where the first stage is an integral scale. So, if you need to scale by a factor of 1/3.4, take the reciprocal (3.4) and truncate it to an integer. This gives us 3. So scale down by a factor of 3 in the first stage. Then go the rest of the way in the second stage. (This is just an educated guess, but it's the first thing I would try.) You might also look for some 3rd-party library that has good scaling methods. (Some have been mentioned on this page.)

Comment: I'm not sure why I wrote that comment, because I think the best approach would be to use the `AffineTransformOp.filter()` method with the BiLinear algorithm like I did in the code I submitted. It will be much faster than getScaledInstance(), and do a better job.

Answer (score 10):

As @Bozho says, you probably want to use `getScaledInstance`.

To understand how `grph.scale(2.0, 2.0)` works however, you could have a look at this code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final int SCALE = 2;

        Image img = new ImageIcon("duke.png").getImage();

        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(SCALE * img.getWidth(null),
                                             SCALE * img.getHeight(null),
                                             BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D grph = (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics();
        grph.scale(SCALE, SCALE);

        // everything drawn with grph from now on will get scaled.

        grph.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        grph.dispose();

        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("duke_double_size.png"));
    }
}
```

Given **duke.png**:
[image]

it produces **duke_double_size.png**:
[image]

Comment: I tried this code, but I didn't get the result shown. The result I got was much more heavily aliased. If you zoom in on the first image in your browser, till you get one about the same size as the second one, you'll get a better idea of what this code produces. (I tried putting the resulting image in this comment, but it didn't work. I guess images aren't allowed in comments.)

Comment: Could you try `grph.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, interpolation);` where `interpolation` is `RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_...` for example `VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC`?

Answer (score 9):

If you do not mind using an external library, [Thumbnailator](http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/) can perform scaling of [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)s.

Thumbnailator will take care of handling the [Java 2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) processing (such as using [`Graphics2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) and setting appropriate [rendering hints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setRenderingHint-java.awt.RenderingHints.Key-java.lang.Object-)) so that a simple fluent API call can be used to resize images:

```
BufferedImage image = Thumbnails.of(originalImage).scale(2.0).asBufferedImage();
```

Although Thumbnailator, as its name implies, is geared toward shrinking images, it will do a decent job enlarging images as well, using bilinear interpolation in its default resizer implementation.

---

*Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of the [Thumbnailator](http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/) library.*

Comment: This is an Excellent library! Thumbnails are just amazing compare to Graphics2D

Comment: Great library! Fits in nicely with Kotlin as well. Also seems more up-to-date than some of the other options.

Answer (score 3):

`scale(..)` works a bit differently. You can use `bufferedImage.getScaledInstance(..)`

Comment: I tried this way, but getScaledInstance returns ToolkitImage, and for my purpose  it doesn't fit to me. thanks

Comment: you can convert it to a BufferedImage by copying its raster to a new BufferedImage. Serach for 'convert image to bufferedimage'

Answer (score 0):

The top-rated answer by trashgod has some minor problems, so I'll post an improved version (due to insufficient reputation points I can't do this as a comment to his solution).

```
BufferedImage before = getBufferedImage(encoded);
int w = before.getWidth();
int h = before.getHeight();
double scaleFactor = 2.0;
BufferedImage after = new BufferedImage((int)(w * scaleFactor), (int)(h * scaleFactor), before.getType());
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
AffineTransformOp scaleOp = 
    new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
after = scaleOp.filter(before, after);
```

Improvements:

- The `after` image has the right dimensions to hold the scaled image
- The `after` image has the same image type as the encoded image (the transformation will fail otherwise)