# Scaling images with Java JAI

Tags: java, image, scaling, jai

I have to scale an image with Java JAI. At the time now, I use the following code:

```
private static RenderedOp scale(RenderedOp image, float scale) {
    ParameterBlock scaleParams = new ParameterBlock();
    scaleParams.addSource(image);
    scaleParams.add(scale).add(scale).add(0.0f).add(0.0f);
    scaleParams.add(Interpolation.getInstance(Interpolation.INTERP_BICUBIC_2));

    // Quality related hints when scaling the image
    RenderingHints scalingHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    scalingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
    scalingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    scalingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
    scalingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
    scalingHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    scalingHints.put(JAI.KEY_BORDER_EXTENDER, BorderExtender.createInstance(BorderExtender.BORDER_COPY));

    return JAI.create("scale", scaleParams, scalingHints);
}
```

Unfortunately, this leads to very bad results, especially because I often have to scale images with a scale factor less than 0.5...

Any advice?

Comment: This line looks suspicious scaleParams.add(scale).add(scale).add(0.0f).add(0.0f);

Comment: Some sample results to illustrate what you mean by bad will also help identify the type of artifact you are experiencing.

Comment: Any reason not to use `AffineTransformOp `? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216635

Comment: @whatnick, you must've never used JAI, that's pretty standard; @Myniva: define "bad"

Comment: @mark-e "bad" means aliasing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)

Comment: I've found an other article covering this problem: http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/mmannion/entry/using_subsample_averaging/ I'll try this solution as soon as possible an report the results here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am guessing you are trying to scale a larger image down to a thumbnail size or some equally large difference from original to scaled image?

If-so, this topic was actually address by Chris Campbell from the Java2D back in 2007 (I am not expecting you knew this, just pointing out that it's a common question) because the new Java2D scaling approaches (RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_*) did not provide an equivalent to the then-deprecated [Image.getScaledInstance(SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING or SCALE_SMOOTH)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) approach.

As it turns out, the SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING or SCALE_SMOOTH approaches in the old Java 1.1 Image.getScaledInstance approach was a fairly expensive, multi-step operation that was doing a lot of work in the background to generate that nice-looking image.

Chris pointed out that the new and "correct" way, using Java2D, to get this same result is an incremental process of scaling the image in-half over and over until the desired image size is reached, preferably using a higher-quality scale like RenderHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC or BILINEAR.

The result comes out almost identical to the original Image.getScaledInstance approach that folks want.

I actually went hunting for this answer a few months ago while writing an image-hosting service and was surprised at how complicated the simple question of "How do I make a nice looking thumbnail in Java?" became.

I eventually create a small Java library (Apache 2, open sourced) that implements 3 different approaches to image scaling in Java using "best practices" including the incremental approach that Chris suggested.

The library is called [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/). You can download and use it as simple as:

```
BufferedImage thumbnail = Scalr.resize(srcImage, 150);
```

There are more options to set and use (e.g. the Quality or Speed of the scaling) but out of the box there are intelligent defaults for everything to make a nice looking scaled image for you so you don't have to worry about more if you don't want to. The library also makes a strong effort to dispose of and avoid any Object allocation that isn't absolutely necessary and dispose of BufferedImage instances immediately if not needed -- it is intended to be code as part of a long-running server app so this was critical.

I've made a few releases of the library already, and if you'd rather just rip out the "good stuff" and do something with it yourself, go for it. It is all on [GitHub](https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr) and none of it is top secret, just an attempt to make people's lives easier.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This library sounds highly intriguing. I love the write-up/motivation my early examples have worked well. We haven't adopted it (yet) pending further analysis.

Comment: @MichaelEaster Glad to hear it is going well so far; I look forward to any additional feedback!

Answer (score 3):

I've obtained good results with [Thumbnailator](http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/). I don't know what JAI.KEY_BORDER_EXTENDER is supposed to do, but I guess the rest of the functionality (antialiasing, dithering, etc) is supported.
I used it to generate grayscale thumbnails of quite big black and white images

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky and you have only Black & White images, then you can use very fast and good quality operation: [SubsampleBinaryToGray](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/operator/SubsampleBinaryToGrayDescriptor.html)