# Java Advanced Imaging Scaling Image

Tags: java, image-processing, scale, imaging, jai

I have a very large image (~200,000x200,000 pixels) in the form of a RenderedImage. I cropped it and then scaled it using JAI's ScaleDescriptor (which returns a RenderedOp). My final image is only about 30x30 but when I call `getAsBufferedImage` (I get the `PlanarImage` first) from the resulting scaled image, it takes several minutes to create. I'm guessing there is some reference back to the original image which is taking such a long time, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know why this would take so long?

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JAI you are building a rendering chain; so when you call .scale it does not actually scale at that point but just adds that to the chain (so in the debugger it will be instant). Only at the end when you go to realize the pixels in your new image does the operation happen.

The amount of scaling you are doing seems like a lot and is may be very expensive. I have not done JAI in a few years; can you specify the scaling algorithm? It might be doing unnecessary interpolation when you can get away with something much simpler.

Comment: @danpaq, thanks, let me try and see what I can come up with. Would you recommend other libraries to do image scaling and cropping on large images? I don't need to use JAI.

Comment: I see in this other question the developer was setting different interpolation settings and rendering hints.

Comment: forgot the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220612/scaling-images-with-java-jai  I'm not sure what the defaults are if you do not set these things. You'll probably want to use SPEED vs QUALITY settings. Although with that much data you may never get something super fast.

Comment: thanks. I tried setting everything to quality and it was still way slow.

Comment: I wonder; do you really want to "scale". 200,000 x 200,000 to 30x30 is crazy. Depending on what the underlying image format is (tiled?), how much you cropped, etc, this could be a very expensive operation. Perhaps you need to define your own JAI operator that does heavy subsampling instead of trying to average all the pixels.

Comment: oops, I meant I set them all to speed - sorry, typo. I don't actually scale from 200k to 30, I crop to a much smaller region first.

Comment: Last simple idea - are you running on a platform that has native JAI support? JAI has both pure Java as well as native libraries. If JAI is not installed properly (or your path is wrong) it will default to the pure java operators which are much slower. You'll have to check the documentation on how to check on this.

Answer (score 0):

try with http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php you will see better picture quality,