# cropping an image at runtime in netbeans

Tags: java, image, swing, crop

How do I allow my web users to crop an image and then upload it on the database, that too at runtime in netbeans?

Comment: `AffineTransformOp`, discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216635), is an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To crop an image try following:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("java.PNG");
Image image = icon.getImage();
image = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(image.getSource(),
            new CropImageFilter(73, 63, 141, 131)));
```

To store in database first save that image as a file and then take column of type=BLOB[may defer in different databases]  and save this image in that column.

---

I have tried this code and its working fine:-

```
      Image image;

      Insets insets;

      JLabel label = new JLabel("asd");

      public TestCls() {
        super();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(TestCls.class.getClassLoader().getResource("user_images/smile/smile.png"));
        image = icon.getImage();
        image = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(image.getSource(),
            new CropImageFilter(1, 1, 15, 15)));

        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
        add(label);
      }

      public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame f = new TestCls();
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.show();
      }
```

Comment: is it better to save the image as itself in the database(as it'll occupy a lot of memory) or should i save only the image path in the database??

Comment: IMO save image in file system and in db only save its path.

Comment: i'v created a label which will display a filechooser whn clickd.

Comment: BufferedImage image=null;

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    int retVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        File myFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

        try {

            image = ImageIO.read(myFile);

            try
            {

                jLabel29.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                jLabel30.setVisible(false);

Comment: @Sia: it is not working because your crop range may be out of image's range. Try to give small values in `new CropImageFilter(73, 63, 141, 131)`.

Comment: I have made a demo at my side and its working fine. Check your image path. Debug code to know whether image is fetched correctly or not.

Comment: the image is being fetched correctly,its displaying the image in its original size(2 large or 2 small) bt adding ur code is makng no difference.

Comment: try calling this: `new CropImageFilter(0, 0, 20, 15)` does it work?

Comment: Something like:   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:158)
        at TestCls.<init>(TestCls.java:35)
        at TestCls.main(TestCls.java:80)

Comment: Okay final try: have you used this `TestCls.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path)` or simply `path` in `new ImageIcon()`? If yes then I did not find anything wrong in it.

Comment: yes i have.im jst not able to debug it.but thanx so much for helping:-)