# java PrintUtilities not working, suggest a way to print the frame of my program

Tags: java, printing

I want to print a screen shot of my app frame when user press button. I also want to give user the option to chooser which printer to use, how many page to print, w/e to print in black and white and etc. java PrintUtilities seem to be the solution, http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-Printing.html, it can print the frame and give user some printing option. however, i use PrintUtilities, it only print 1/4 of my frame, the top right corner. can someone tell me how to fix this or suggest a better way to print that give user some printing options like select which printer to use. thx

Comment: i figure out from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026822/printing-a-large-swing-component, use scale function on the Graphics variable in print function in PrintUtilities to fit the frame onto screen