# Java JTabbedPane Inset Color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, jtabbedpane

I was wondering how you would get the color of the inset of a JTabbedPane. I cannot seem to get this color. Every attempt I make I get 236,236,236 which is the outside frame color, where the inside frame color is about 10 darker, 227,227,227 (using the built in apple color meter).

I am setting the look and feel using UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

You can see this in an image that I found on the internet. http://pagesofinterest.net/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/Quaqua-Maven-Netbeans.jpg Where the words "Panel's Title" is the area that I am getting the lighter color that is not useful to me. Inside the round corners is the darker color I am trying to obtain. I tried getting the color of the content pane to no avail.

Thanks for all your help!

**EDIT:**Added code! As you see, I am trying to get the color of the area inside the rounded corners(if your on a mac) not the color of the frame or the tabs that say "1" "2". I have attached a photo and I am trying to get the background color of the portion that says "Here" Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

```
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class main {
JFrame frame;
Container c1 = new Container();
Container c2 = new Container();
JTabbedPane top = new JTabbedPane();
static main GUI;
public void createGUI(){
    frame = new JFrame();
    Container c = frame.getContentPane();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    top = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    top.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    top.setFocusable(false);
    top.addTab("1", c1);
    top.addTab("2", c2);
    frame.setSize(315,450);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    c.add(top);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
} 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
    GUI = new main();
    GUI.createGUI();
}
}
```

**EDIT:** camickr, Here is a screenshot of the UIManager Defaults. Unfortunately none of there colors in the are the correct color that the inset is.

[image: UI Manager Defaults]

Comment: Can you please put your code here, that would be great and it will easy for us to give you advice :)

Comment: The color is a semi gradient, ranging from about RGB/195, 195, 195 to about RGB/208, 208, 208

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. On my mac, when I run the program, there is no gradient at all when I am inside the round corners in the box with "Here" in it from the screen shot(using mac digital color meter). The issue is I cannot statically define this color, because on Windows, this color is entirely different. I need to find a way to get this color pragmatically so I can use it in my program later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use [UIMangaer Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) to find the color.

Comment: Thank you camickr, I have edited the OP to provide more information pertaining to your response.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `paintComponent()` to use a `GradientPaint` in the tab's background, as shown below. A few notes,

- Let the content adopt the preferred size of it contents, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).
- Construct the GUI in the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Use conventional Java names.

Addendum: *the elements are not always in the same spot, so I do not know what place to get the color*.

It sounds like you want to match a color used internally by the `TabbedPaneUI` delegate. One approach would be as follows:

- Render a `BufferedImage` of the component, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7028497/230513).
- Determine the coordinates of a `Point` in `top` relative to the top of `c1`.

  ```
  Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(c1, 0, -1, top);
  ```
- Obtain the color using `getRGB()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742841/230513); use [`Zoom`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742841/230513) to verify the result.

[image: Main image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16625260/230513 */
public class Main {

    JFrame frame;
    Container c1 = new GradientPanel();
    Container c2 = new GradientPanel();
    JTabbedPane top = new JTabbedPane();

    private static class GradientPanel extends JPanel {

        public GradientPanel() {
            this.add(new JLabel("Here"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            GradientPaint p = new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.white,
                getWidth(), getHeight(), Color.gray);
            g2d.setPaint(p);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    public void createGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        top = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        top.addTab("1", c1);
        top.addTab("2", c2);
        frame.add(top);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main().createGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Trashgod, Thank you for your response, but I do not want to change the color at all, or put in any gradients. I just want to get the color.

Comment: Ah, I see you want to match the color, not change it. I don't think `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel` exposes that color as a `UIManager` property. You could use `Robot`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742841/230513).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am unsure how to implement what you reference in Robot. Could you help me use that to get the color?

Comment: Run the program and mouse over the area of interest to see the color; mine says `0xFFDFDFDF`.

Comment: I know what the color code is, the issue is I have to get this on every computer every time that the program starts. So every time I start the program I need to have the color of the background of the container. On Mac this is a greyish color. On Windows it is almost white. The issue is not getting it once, the issue is getting it every time the program starts. I wanted to do something like jtabpane.getBackground(), but this does not get the color of the container, just the color of the tab. I need to find a way to get the color of the container. Thanks again, hopefully this is more clear now

Comment: You can render into a `bufferedImage`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7028497/230513), and use `getRGB()`.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but can you help me do that. I am struggling with how to approach that. There is no way to get the container color? The only way would be to take a screen shot of the container then get that color? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know where you're stuck. Please edit your question with an update of your [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach based on the examples cited.

Comment: The issue is I this is just a very small app that I threw together to show what portion of the frame I needed the color of. The issue is when the frame opens, all the elements are not always in the same spot, so I do not know what place to get the color of.

Comment: @dannyn382: I outlined an approach above.