# How to rescale painted contents of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, rescale

I have a window which contains upper `JPanel` where figures are painted and the lower `JPanel` where figures are listed in the `JList` the list looks like:

```
[minature][figure.toString()]
```

The minature is `JPanel` of a size `10x10`. I would like it to contain minature of drawn figure in the upper Panel. By it I  mean.

```
class minaturePanel{
Figure f;....
public void paint(Graphics g){
  g.drawFullSizeFigure(f);
  g.rescaleWholeInsidesOfThePanel();

}
}
```

Comment: What is the figure? Ie image, shape?

Comment: Figure is a class which conains method `draw(Graphics g){...g.fillRect etc.}

Answer (score 3):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7028497/230513) paints into a `BufferedImage` and uses `AffineTransformOp` to do the scaling.

[image]

You may also want to look at [`JScrollNavigator`](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t21355.html), examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744971/230513). It lets you  navigate on a thumbnail image of your entire component, seen at full size in an adjacent scroll pane.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to draw your full figure to an image, return the image, and then rescale the image then draw the image on the panel which will be the right size as the panel now. Actually you can rescale the image while drawing it.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Figure` has no capacity to scale it self.  You can use a `AffineTransformation` to scale the `Graphics` context your self.  Just don't forget to restore the previous transformation...

Check out [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) for more details.