# Painting JLabel cuts off HTML Text

Tags: java, html, spring, jlabel, bufferedimage

I'm trying to paint a JLabel to a BufferedImage using html as text but it always prints the text in the middle (vertically), and cuts off the text on the right.

Here is my code:

```
public static void test() throws IOException
{
    int width = 100;

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("<html><body><p>asdf asdfasdf asdfsdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdfa sdfasd fasdf asdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdfasdfa sdfasdf</p></body></html>");
    Dimension size = getPreferredSize(label.getText(), true, width);

    label.setSize(size);

    BufferedImage image =
            new BufferedImage(
                    label.getWidth(),
                    label.getHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 900);
    label.paint(g);

    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("testImage.png"));
}

private static final JLabel resizer = new JLabel();

public static java.awt.Dimension getPreferredSize(
        String html,
        boolean width,
        int prefSize)
{

    resizer.setText(html);

    View view =
            (View) resizer
                    .getClientProperty(javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML.propertyKey);

    view.setSize(width ? prefSize : 0, width ? 0 : prefSize);

    float w = view.getPreferredSpan(View.X_AXIS);
    float h = view.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);

    return new java.awt.Dimension((int) Math.ceil(w), (int) Math.ceil(h));
}
```

And here is the resulting image:

[image]

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to make it wrap?

Comment: Yes, and why is starts painting half-way down the label.

Comment: 1) See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17541765/418556) for tips on using HTML.  I suspect it will be as easy as setting the width in CSS.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score -1):

I think the html word wrapping is handled by something in the swing thread loop, if you are doing this form that loop as a actionlistener then it can't recalculate the html