# Scaling a bitmap in to another bitmap, best 'manual' way?

Tags: java

The bitmap is nothing more then a `int[] pixels = new int[width * height]`;

I am using in this way:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,RGB);
int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

'do rendering here on pixels[], for instance load an image using `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(URL)`;

```
Graphics g;
g.drawImage(img, 0,0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
```

Now during the 'do rendering here on pixels' lots of stuff can happen, coloring the textures (they are gray-scales) but I also need to rescale them. Though I don't know "the best way" to do this.

All 'bitmaps' are just an array of ints.

Scaling can be done in steps on 0.1 or 0.01 or 3.
I personally thought something like:

```
for(int yy = 0; yy < tex.height; yy++){
    for(int xx = 0; xx < tex.width; xx++){
        int px = tex.getPixel(yy * tex.width + xx);
        this.putPixel( (y*this.width)+((int)((yy*scale) * tex.width)) + (x) + ((int)(xx*scale)));
    }
}
```

But I have no clue if this would be 'the right' way. Or if there are other/better ways.

Comment: If more information is needed, please do ask.

Comment: See also `AffineTransformOp`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage/4216635#4216635).

Comment: Yeah I had seen that one, though I intent not to keep a reference to the BufferedImage object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there is no right way. You have to make a trade-off between quality and performance.

The wikipedia page on [image scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) has a good overview of methods.

Comment: Both is not really of the essence, there will at most be about 3different textures with a ~32x32 grid, the viewport has a grid of ~320x240. All same textures will have same verything, so they will probably be the same object reference, just drawn on a different part of the viewport.

Comment: I've got the most simplest version to work, running great. Accepted your answer since indeed it is true.