# Java: reading, converting and resizing of images

Tags: java, image, resize

I need to read image in java.
Then I should to convert it to 565RGB
In addition it would be good to resize this image to 320 x 240.
How should I do it? Help me please.

I know such information:
1)It is possible to read image by its URL.

```
ImageIcon imgThisImg = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
```

2) It is possible to create image instances that supports 565RGB.

```
BufferedImage bufImg = new BufferedImage(320, 240, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB);
```

3)BufferedImage inherits ImageIcon , so it is possible to perform such operation

```
Image imgPicture ...
BufferedImage  bufImg = (BufferedImage) imgPicture;
```

But I haven't any idea, will `bufImg`  in this case have `BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB format`?
How to stretch, to squeeze or to cut this picture to get size 320 x 240?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most convenient method to read image from any source (File,Stream,URL) is

```
BufferedImage bufImg = ImageIO.read( imageURL );
```

Then to answer your question you should check this post
[How to scale a BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage).

Comment: Thank you for answer. But what about changing format to 565RGB? Can I gain this goal in such way                                                                    BufferedImage bufImg = new BufferedImage(320, 240, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_565_RGB);                                    BufferedImage bufImg1 = ImageIO.read( imageURL );
    bufImg=bufImg1;                                                      will bufImg in necessary format? how to define it?