# how do I scale a BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I have viewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage), but it does not seem to actually answer the question that I have.  I have a, image file, that may be any resolution.  I need to load that image into a `BufferedImage` Object at a specific resolution (say, for this example, 800x800).  I know the Image class can use `getScaledInstance()` to scale the image to a new size, but I then cannot figure out how to get it back to a `BufferedImage`.  Is there a simple way to scale a Buffered Image to a specific size?

**NOTE** I I do not want to scale the image by a specific factor, I want to take an image and make is a specific size.

Comment: **I do not want to scale the image by a specific factor, I want to take an image and make is a specific size** This can be done easily: `factor = originalSize\newSize;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this? :

```
 /**
 * Resizes an image using a Graphics2D object backed by a BufferedImage.
 * @param srcImg - source image to scale
 * @param w - desired width
 * @param h - desired height
 * @return - the new resized image
 */
private BufferedImage getScaledImage(Image srcImg, int w, int h){
    BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D g2 = resizedImg.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g2.dispose();
    return resizedImg;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new BufferedImage of the size you want and then perform a scaled paint of the original image into the new one:

```
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(new_width, new_height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, new_width, new_height, null);
g.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

see this website  [Link1](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-resize-an-image-in-java/)

Or 
This [Link2](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Advanced-Graphics/ScalingaBufferedImage.htm)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the input @KarlRichter . I'll definitely update the answer soon.