# Reduce image size (bytes) in ITextPDF

Tags: java, itext

I'm using the itext PDF library to build a very image-intensive PDF document in Java. Each page has a dozen images on it. The original source images are very high resolution, and I'm using `scaleToFit` to render the image to the size I need.

The problem I have is that the PDF document is still very large. My understanding is that the entire original high resolution image is being included, and the scaling I'm using only affects the actual rendering, not the size of the image that's included in the file.

I've verified this by removing the scaling — the pages were rendered with the high resolution images overlapping each other and the edge of pages, and the PDF was the same size as when the scaling was in place.

So, here's the question — how can I reduce the size of the PDF file by scaling down each image? If I lose a little bit of image quality that's ok. Rescaling the source images manually will be difficult.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I've found a way to do it. I now load the image into a `BufferedImage`, and then scale that using the hints found here: [how do I scale a BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367324/how-do-i-scale-a-bufferedimage?lq=1).

This gives me a `BufferedImage` — I then convert this into an iText image using

```
        Image returnedImage = Image.getInstance ( pcb, bufferedImage, quality );
```

Where `quality` is currently 0.6. That's acceptable for the work I'm doing.

Comment: FWIW, using this technique, my test file has gone from 29MB to 3MB.

Comment: Upvoted the answer. Also: it's good practice to accept good answers, even if you answered the question yourself.

Comment: I tried to do that, but it said I had to wait 2 days until I could answer my own question. Come back and done that now.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie what if we want to do this with itext7? seems that it is possible as well (see the link) but its quality is not acceptable actually. https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/image-examples/clone-reduce-image

Comment: @webyildirim (1.) don't comment on a question that dates from 2013. Almost no one will notice your comment. Post a new question instead. That won't be a duplicate question, because this question is about iText 5 and yours is about iText 7. However: (2.) your allegation "the quality is not acceptable actually" is strange, since *you* decide on the quality. If a quality of 0.5 is not acceptable, use a quality of 0.8. The size reduction will be lower, but the quality will be better. Common sense should tell you not to expect significant size reduction without significant quality reduction.