# how to adapt the size of graphics to the size of a pdf page java

Tags: java, pdf, graphics, itext

I am trying to save a graphics in pdf file using this code :

```
if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
    PdfWriter writer = null;

    try {
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Simulation_Report.pdf"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reports.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    document.open();

    try {
        document.add(new Paragraph("Simulation Report"));
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reports.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    document.newPage();

    try {
        document.add(new Paragraph("Simulation"));

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

        cb.saveState();

        PdfTemplate pdfTemplate = cb.createTemplate(750,750);
        Graphics2D g2 = pdfTemplate.createGraphics(750, 750);

        Drawer drawer = new Drawer();
        drawer.setSource(new File(jTextField1.getText()));
        drawer.paintComponent(g2);

        cb.addTemplate(pdfTemplate, 10, 10);
        g2.dispose();
        cb.restoreState();

    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reports.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    document.close();
```

but when I open the saved file (pdf file) I can't see the totality of the graphics, I just see about 60% of the graphics , so  how adapt the size of the graphics with the size of the pdf page A4
How can I fix that ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a contradiction in your code.

I see:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
```

This means that you are creating a document with size 595 x 842 user units (1 user unit = 1 point by default).

However, I also see you creating a `PdfTemplate` that measures 750 x 750 user units:

```
PdfTemplate pdfTemplate = cb.createTemplate(750,750);
```

And you add this template with an offset of 10 user units:

```
cb.addTemplate(pdfTemplate, 10, 10);
```

How to resolve that contradiction? You have two options:

**Option 1: adapt the page to your graphics:**

I assume that you want a margin of 10 user units on every side, so the dimension of your page should be at least 770 x 770 user units (750 to accommodate the image plus 10 times two for the margins on either side).
In that case, you should create your document like this:

```
Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(770, 770));
```

Now you are creating a document with a page that corresponds with the size of the graphic you want to add.

**Option 2: adapt the size of your graphics to the size of your page:**

Throw away this code:

```
cb.saveState();
PdfTemplate pdfTemplate = cb.createTemplate(750,750);
Graphics2D g2 = pdfTemplate.createGraphics(750, 750);
Drawer drawer = new Drawer();
drawer.setSource(new File(jTextField1.getText()));
drawer.paintComponent(g2);
cb.addTemplate(pdfTemplate, 10, 10);
g2.dispose();
cb.restoreState();
```

Replace it with:

```
PdfTemplate pdfTemplate = cb.createTemplate(750,750);
Graphics2D g2 = pdfTemplate.createGraphics(750, 750);
Drawer drawer = new Drawer();
drawer.setSource(new File(jTextField1.getText()));
drawer.paintComponent(g2);
g2.dispose();
Image img = Image.getInstance(pdfTemplate);
img.scaleToFit(575, 822);
img.setAbsolutePosition(10, 10);
document.add(img);
```

As you can see, we scale the image so that it measures 20 user units less in width (and height) than the page. That's because your code indicates that you want a margin of 10 user units for the image. Now we are sure that the image will fit the page (and even leave a margin of at least 10 points).

We define the absolute position at `(10, 10)` which were the coordinates you used in your `addTemplate()` method and we add the image to the document.

Don't worry: wrapping a `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image` object will not rasterize the image. If the template contained vector data, the vector data will be preserved.

Comment: thx for your reponse I tried your code but I have problem with this part of the problem '' Image img = Image.getInstance(pdfTemplate);
img.scaleToFit(575, 822);
img.setAbsolutePosition(10, 10);
document.add(img);"

Comment: It is not sufficient to say that you have a problem. You also have to explain the problem.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie What if we want to do this in itext7 ?

Comment: @webyildirim See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129025/reduce-image-size-bytes-in-itextpdf/15130278?noredirect=1#comment88455639_15130278 Changing the size of a page in iText 7 is easy. See the tutorial on the official website. Changing the size of an image in iText 7 is easy. See the tutorial on the official web site. Please don't waste my time! Read the tutorials before asking questions! https://developers.itextpdf.com/books