# How to convert an iText Image into an AWT BufferedImage?

Tags: java, itext

In an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129025/reduce-image-size-bytes-in-itextpdf) @Andrew says "I now load the image into a BufferedImage", however I can't figure out how to do that. I assume the gist of it is converting the iText Image object to an AWT BufferedImage (or AWT Image and then to AWT BufferedImage). I am limited to using iText 2.1.7 version.

Answer (score 0):

I now think he was using the word "image" in a generic sense and not in the iText Image object sense. In my case I have found that I can load a PDF image into a BufferedImage using Apache PDFBox.