# How to get a BufferedImage from a SVG?

Tags: java, svg, batik

I am using Batik to handle SVG images. Is there any way to get a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` from a SVG-file?

I know there are transcoders, with which I could transcode the SVG into, for example, a PNG and then load that PNG with `ImageIO.read()`. But I don't want to have the temporary file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/), something like this:

```
public static BufferedImage rasterize(File svgFile) throws IOException {

    final BufferedImage[] imagePointer = new BufferedImage[1];

    // Rendering hints can't be set programatically, so
    // we override defaults with a temporary stylesheet.
    // These defaults emphasize quality and precision, and
    // are more similar to the defaults of other SVG viewers.
    // SVG documents can still override these defaults.
    String css = "svg {" +
            "shape-rendering: geometricPrecision;" +
            "text-rendering:  geometricPrecision;" +
            "color-rendering: optimizeQuality;" +
            "image-rendering: optimizeQuality;" +
            "}";
    File cssFile = File.createTempFile("batik-default-override-", ".css");
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(cssFile, css);

    TranscodingHints transcoderHints = new TranscodingHints();
    transcoderHints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_XML_PARSER_VALIDATING, Boolean.FALSE);
    transcoderHints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOM_IMPLEMENTATION,
            SVGDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation());
    transcoderHints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT_NAMESPACE_URI,
            SVGConstants.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI);
    transcoderHints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT, "svg");
    transcoderHints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_USER_STYLESHEET_URI, cssFile.toURI().toString());

    try {

        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(new FileInputStream(svgFile));

        ImageTranscoder t = new ImageTranscoder() {

            @Override
            public BufferedImage createImage(int w, int h) {
                return new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            }

            @Override
            public void writeImage(BufferedImage image, TranscoderOutput out)
                    throws TranscoderException {
                imagePointer[0] = image;
            }
        };
        t.setTranscodingHints(transcoderHints);
        t.transcode(input, null);
    }
    catch (TranscoderException ex) {
        // Requires Java 6
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new IOException("Couldn't convert " + svgFile);
    }
    finally {
        cssFile.delete();
    }

    return imagePointer[0];
}
```

Comment: is there an advantage to creating an array of imagePointer vs just assigning imagePointer to a local variable like this http://bbgen.net/blog/2011/06/java-svg-to-bufferedimage/?

Comment: Actually no. It's just an workaround to avoid compilation errors in the `writeImage` method.

Comment: I figured out how to set size by using e.g `transcoderHints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH...`, but how would I scale the output image by a factor?

Comment: @vincent "by a factor" you mean zoom X%?

Comment: @elias That's correct. Your script somehow determines size automatically, which is great. However I can not scale that using a percent value. I can extract the size separately somehow I guess and use that in the hints. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Simply rescale the image at `createImage` method using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage). And the new value for width and height is `current * (factor/100))`.

Comment: So try to do the same with the transcoderHints instead. `transcoderHints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, current * (factor/100))`

Comment: If I do it before I don't habe the current dimension. And if I do it in the function it's not picket up (too late)

Answer (score 16):

A very easy way is to use the [TwelveMonkeys lib](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) which adds additional image type support to java's `ImageIO`

So for example you just add these to your maven (or copy the needed jars):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>imageio-batik</artifactId> <!-- svg -->
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>batik</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
        <version>1.6-1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then you just read it with

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(svg-file);
```

To check if the svg reader is registered correctly you could print out the image readers:

```
Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("SVG");
while (readers.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("reader: " + readers.next());
}
```

The lib also supports additional params, see [readme on github](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys).

Comment: This is weird lib. It haven't online documentation. It haven't examples. It have problem with dependency (see your post with third party). And it's have problem with icon resize-load. I was led to a small amount of code and regretted it.

Comment: This didn't work for me with Java13. I hat to search current versions for the libraries:   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
   <artifactId>imageio-batik</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
   <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
   <version>1.11</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Is the version `1.6-1` or `1.6.1`?

Comment: Do you know how to setup build.gradle or pom.xml to setup this lib? I have tried multiple combinations (or even adding all), but none of them works. Here is the issue: https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues/729

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use.  It's an extension of BufferedImage with its own static factory that can be used wherever a BufferedImage is used.  I wrote it so that any call to getScaledInstance(w, h, hint) will render from the SVG, not the rasterized image.  <strike>A side-effect of this is that the scaling hint parameter has no meaning; you can just pass 0 or DEFAULT to that.</strike>  <strike>It renders lazily - only when graphics data is requested - so the load / scale cycle shouldn't give you too much overhead.</strike>

Edit: I added support using the above CSS config for scaling quality hints.
Edit 2: Lazy rendering wasn't working consistently; I put the render() call into the constructor.

It has the following dependencies:

- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim
- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge
- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt
- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder
- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util
- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext
- commons-logging:commons-logging

When I made this, I used batik 1.8; YMMV.

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Composite;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SAXSVGDocumentFactory;
import org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeContext;
import org.apache.batik.bridge.DocumentLoader;
import org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder;
import org.apache.batik.bridge.UserAgent;
import org.apache.batik.bridge.UserAgentAdapter;
import org.apache.batik.gvt.GraphicsNode;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscodingHints;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder;
import org.apache.batik.util.SVGConstants;
import org.apache.batik.util.XMLResourceDescriptor;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.svg.SVGDocument;

public class SVGImage extends BufferedImage {
    private static class BufferedImageTranscoder extends ImageTranscoder {
        private BufferedImage image = null;
        @Override
        public BufferedImage createImage(int arg0, int arg1) {

            return image;
        }
        private void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
            this.image = image;
        }
        @Override
        public void writeImage(BufferedImage arg0, TranscoderOutput arg1) throws TranscoderException {
        }
    }

    final static GVTBuilder builder = new GVTBuilder();
    final static SAXSVGDocumentFactory factory = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName());
    final static UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgentAdapter();
    final static DocumentLoader loader = new DocumentLoader(userAgent);
    final static BridgeContext bridgeContext = new BridgeContext(userAgent, loader);
    static {
        bridgeContext.setDynamicState(BridgeContext.STATIC);
    }
    final static private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SVGImage.class);
    private static final Map<Integer, String> scaleQuality = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    static {
        String css = "svg {" +
                "shape-rendering: %s;" +
                "text-rendering:  %s;" +
                "color-rendering: %s;" +
                "image-rendering: %s;" +
        "}";
        String precise = "geometricPrecision";
        String quality = "optimizeQuality";
        String speed = "optimizeSpeed";
        String crisp = "crispEdges";
        String legible = "optimizeLegibility";
        String auto = "auto";

        scaleQuality.put(SCALE_DEFAULT, String.format(css, auto, auto, auto, auto));
        scaleQuality.put(SCALE_SMOOTH, String.format(css, precise, precise, quality, quality));
        scaleQuality.put(SCALE_REPLICATE, String.format(css, speed, speed, speed, speed));
        scaleQuality.put(SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING, String.format(css, crisp, legible, auto, auto));
        scaleQuality.put(SCALE_FAST, String.format(css, speed, speed, speed, speed));
    }
    final static BufferedImageTranscoder transcoder = new BufferedImageTranscoder();

    public static SVGImage fromSvg(URL resource) throws IOException {
        InputStream rs = null;
        try {
            rs = resource.openStream();
            SVGDocument svg = factory.createSVGDocument(resource.toString(), rs);
            return fromSvgDocument(resource, svg);
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                try { rs.close(); } catch (IOException ioe) {}
            }
        }
    }
    public static SVGImage fromSvgDocument(URL resource, SVGDocument doc) {
        GraphicsNode graphicsNode = builder.build(bridgeContext, doc);
        Double width = graphicsNode.getBounds().getWidth();
        Double height = graphicsNode.getBounds().getHeight();
        return new SVGImage(resource, doc, width.intValue(), height.intValue(), SCALE_DEFAULT);
    }
    boolean hasRendered = false;
    private int scalingHint = SCALE_DEFAULT;
    final SVGDocument svg;
    final URL svgUrl;
    private SVGImage(URL resource, SVGDocument doc, int width, int height, int hints) {
        super(width, height, TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        scalingHint = hints;
        svgUrl = resource;
        svg = doc;
        render();
    }
    @Override
    public void coerceData(boolean isAlphaPremultiplied) {
        if (!hasRendered) { render(); }
        super.coerceData(isAlphaPremultiplied);
    }
    @Override
    public WritableRaster copyData(WritableRaster outRaster) {
        if (!hasRendered) { render(); }
        return super.copyData(outRaster);
    }
    private File createCSS(String css) {
        FileWriter cssWriter = null;
        File cssFile = null;
        try {
            cssFile = File.createTempFile("batik-default-override-", ".css");
            cssFile.deleteOnExit();
            cssWriter = new FileWriter(cssFile);
            cssWriter.write(css);
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            log.warn("Couldn't write stylesheet; SVG rendered with Batik defaults");
        } finally {

            if (cssWriter != null) {
                try { 
                    cssWriter.flush();
                    cssWriter.close(); 
                } catch (IOException ioe) {}
            }
        }
        return cssFile;
    }
    @Override
    public WritableRaster getAlphaRaster() {
        if (!hasRendered) { render(); }
        return super.getAlphaRaster();
    }
    @Override
    public Raster getData() {
        if (!hasRendered) { render(); }
        return super.getData();
    }

    @Override
    public Graphics getGraphics() {
        if (!hasRendered) { render(); }
        return super.getGraphics();
    }
    public Image getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints) {
        SVGImage newImage = new SVGImage(svgUrl, svg, width, height, hints);
        return newImage;
    }
    private void render() {
        TranscodingHints hints = new TranscodingHints();
        hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, new Float(getWidth()));
        hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, new Float(getHeight()));
        hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_XML_PARSER_VALIDATING, Boolean.FALSE);
        hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOM_IMPLEMENTATION, svg.getImplementation());
        hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT_NAMESPACE_URI, SVGConstants.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI);
        hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_DOCUMENT_ELEMENT, "svg");
        String css = scaleQuality.get(scalingHint);
        File cssFile = null;
        if (css != null) {
            cssFile = createCSS(css);
            if (cssFile != null) {
                hints.put(ImageTranscoder.KEY_USER_STYLESHEET_URI, cssFile.toURI().toString());
            }
        }
        transcoder.setTranscodingHints(hints);
        transcoder.setImage(this);
        // This may be a re-render, if the scaling quality hint has changed.
        // As such, we force the image into overwrite mode, and kick it back when we're done / fail
        Graphics2D gfx = (Graphics2D) super.getGraphics();
        Composite savedComposite = gfx.getComposite();
        gfx.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
        try {
            transcoder.transcode(new TranscoderInput(svg), null);
            hasRendered = true;
        } catch (TranscoderException te) {
            log.warn("Could not transcode " + svgUrl.getPath() + " to raster image; you're going to get a blank BufferedImage of the correct size.");
        } finally {
            gfx.setComposite(savedComposite);
            if (cssFile != null) {
                cssFile.delete();
            }
        }
    }
    public void setScalingHint(int hint) {
        this.scalingHint = hint;
        // Forces a re-render
        this.hasRendered = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, I think I'll be stealing the CSS transcoder hint above to emulate the scaling hints from BufferedImage.

Answer (score 2):

9 years later here is an other solution with Batik :

> implementation 'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-all:1.14'
>
> implementation 'org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-swing:1.14'

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.Transcoder;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class SvgToRasterizeImageConverter {

    public BufferedImage transcodeSVGToBufferedImage(File file, int width, int height) {
        // Create a PNG transcoder.
        Transcoder t = new PNGTranscoder();

        // Set the transcoding hints.
        t.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, (float) width);
        t.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, (float) height);
        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            // Create the transcoder input.
            TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(inputStream);

            // Create the transcoder output.
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(outputStream);

            // Save the image.
            t.transcode(input, output);

            // Flush and close the stream.
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            // Convert the byte stream into an image.
            byte[] imgData = outputStream.toByteArray();
            return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgData));

        } catch (IOException | TranscoderException e) {
            log.error("Conversion error", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is *so* close to what I need, but unfortunately it fails if the InputStream isn't based on a File object (like if it's a S3Object.getObjectContent() stream).

Comment: @PaulTomblin What is happening ? You have an exception ?

Comment: Found it on the batik developers list from 18 years ago. They’re not going to fix it. https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10787

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the answer above, but this answer is to help with [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35812847/17382150) from [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774398/patrick).

Using the [Twelve Monkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) library currently requires the following pom entries:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
    <version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>imageio-batik</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```