# how to convert a VML to SVG or VML to a bitmap image by java code?

Tags: java, svg, vml

I've been looking for a long time for a way to have a bitmap from a VML document.I have no problem for anything except for IE (of course) because I'm using ext-js pie chart it will make chart as svg on ie 9 but it was making vml at ie8.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following process:

- Choose an XSLT processor
- Convert VML to SVG via [vml2svg.xsl and its dependencies](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vectorconverter/files/VectorConverter1.2/VectorConverter1.2/VectorConverter1.2.zip/download)
- Convert SVG to a BufferedImage using Batik or SVG Salamander
- Save the BufferedImage as a bitmap

**References**

- [How to get a BuffererImage from a SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435671/1113772)
- [How to make a color transparent in a BufferedImage and save as PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665406/1113772)
- [SVG Salamander source: ImageSVG.java](https://java.net/projects/svgsalamander/sources/svn/content/trunk/svg-core/src/main/java/com/kitfox/svg/ImageSVG.java)