# Java ImageIO.read(URL) returning null when it shouldn't

Tags: java, image, url, jar, javax.imageio

Okay so I have spent about 15 hours trying to figure this out. I am working on this program that gets exported to a non-runnable jar file. The issue is I am trying to load an image in the jar and set it to a variable.

I HAVE looked at other posts and I think I have tried everything I could find but nothing seems to work.

I am not asking how to FIND the image as I can get the URL of the image, but then ImageIO.read(URL) is not throwing any exception, but returning null. The image is a .png which I have heard is compatible with ImageIO.read(). I am using an API so that is what the log() lines are.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

My Project:

```
    Project
    ->src
    -->package
    --->Main.java
    --->paint.png
```

My Code:

In my main method:
(mainPaint is a private Image)

```
    mainPaint = getImage("paint.png");
```

The method:

```
private Image getImage(String fileName) {

    URL url = getClass().getResource(fileName);
    BufferedImage image = null;

    log(url.toString()); // To make sure I have the correct file
    // returning jar:file:/C:/Users/Me/MyJar.jar!/package/paint.png

    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        log("Error converting url to image.");
        // This is not happening
    }

    if (image == null) {
        log("Image is null.");
        // This is happening
    }

    return image;
}
```

Is the URL invalid? Am I just missing something? I'm just trying to save the local image in the jar as an Image object, I feel like this is way too difficult for what I am trying to do.

EDIT:
I also just tried making mainPaint a BufferedImage and using:

```
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(fileName));
    if(image == null) {
        log("Image is null");
    }
    log("Height: " + image.getHeight(null));
    log("Width: " + image.getWidth(null));

    BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Draw the image on to the buffered image
    Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
    bGr.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    bGr.dispose();

    // Return the buffered image
    return bimage;
```

The height and width of the image are returning -1?

Comment: ImageIO.read catches a lesser exception IllegalArgumentException - if input is null. is also possible so dont get too excited

Comment: I'm printing out url.toString() and it is printing the location of the image, so url is not null.

Comment: @gpasch `ImageIO.read` *throws* an `IllegalArgumentException` if input is `null`. It doesn't catch that exception.

Comment: @Opoz Can you attach your PNG (preferably extracted from the JAR, in case it has been mangled in any way)? Without the file in question ([*complete and verifiable*, remember?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) we can only guess and speculate...

Answer (score 1):

`ImageIO.read()` will not load SVG files, so if your images are in SVG formate you will need to add plugins to it to support SVG

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435671/how-to-get-a-buffererimage-from-a-svg) is another SO post that explain where you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

ImageIO.read() will load only GIF, PNG, JPEG, BMP, and WBMP image types.
Any other image type will return null without error.

It could answer to your question .

Comment: This is not correct. The ist of supported formats is here https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formats.html