# How to give resolution to a new generated image?

Tags: java, swing

I can write the image but its default resolution is 600x450.
I want to specify my own resolution.

```
public void save(String path, String name) throws IOException 
{
            int x ;
            int y;
            x=scaled.getHeight();
            y=scaled.getWidth();

            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(y);

            if (scaled != null) 
            {  
                name += scaled.getWidth() + "x" + scaled.getHeight();
                ImageIO.write(scaled, "png", new File(path + File.separator + name + ".png"));
            } 
            else 
            {
                throw new NullPointerException("Scaled instance is null");
            }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume `scaled` is a field image. Also, I will assume you're not getting a `NullPointerException`.

You can use `scaled.getImageData().getScaled(int x, int y)` to return a new scaled image with your own **x** and **y**.

Like so:

```
ImageData newData = scaled.getImageData().scaledTo(int x, int y);
Image newScaledImage = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), newData);
ImageIO.write(newScaledImage , "png", new File(path + File.separator + name + ".png"));
newScaledImage.dispose();
```

Comment: Please cite the API for `getImageData()` and `getScaled()`.

Comment: yes i have done it. i have made that thing possible. and it also first time. thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`AffineTransformOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216635/230513), or [`Image#getScaledInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15961412/230513).

Comment: yes i have done it. i have made that thing possible. and it also first time. thank you everyone.