# Displaying Java BufferedImage on MacBook with Retina display does not work

Tags: java, swing, osx-mountain-lion, retina-display

I have written a Java7-Application that creates a `BufferedImage` that gets drawn on by a background thread whenever the user changes something that has influence on the image. The problem is that when displaying the image, the correct image gets shown only for a few seconds, then an erratic imgage (in the right size) with rests of the frame buffer from the system is shown; see image below:

[image]

Here is what it should look like:

[image: correct image]

As soon as the drawing thread has finished, the `BufferedImage` will be drawn onto a `JPanel` component after being transformed with an `AffineTransformation` to reflect a certain zoom level.

The size of the `BufferedImage` is determined by a fixed number that is not dependent on the resolution of the MacBook or the `JFrame` (usually quite high, something like 4000x2000). The panel in which the `BufferedImage` gets drawn is inside a `ScrollPane` that adjusts to the size of the panel. It does not matter whether the `BufferedImage` is written over or created new each time a new version is drawn by the thread.

I have tested the tool on windows, a MacBook without retina display and three MacBooks with retina display, on all machines without retina display, the tool works perfectly. Any ideas?

Edit: This is how the program works: The class `HexaVisExplorer` is the `JFrame` GUI built with NetBeans of the project. It keeps a `ScrollPane`, and a `VisualizationPanel` that is the content of the `ScrollPane`, and whenever the user changes a property that has influence on the resulting image, the `ActionListener` for the component calls a method in the `VisualizationPanel`. There, a property is set and a `Thread` gets initialized and started that, based on the properties set in `VisualizationPanel`, will draw a new `BufferedImage`. When this is done, the new `BufferedImage` will be saved to the `VisualizationPanel`, which then will be repainted with an overridden `paintComponent()`, where the image will be transformed using a `java.awt.geom.AffineTransform` for efficient zooming. Finally, the viewport of the scroll pane gets modified to reflect the new image size. Here is the code:

Class HexavisExplorer.java

```
public class HexaVisExplorer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private VisualizationPanel visualizationPanel;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;

    public HexaVisExplorer() {
        //...Example where a component listener calls a method in VisualizationPanel.java to set a property
        polygonBorderCheckbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                visualizationPanel.setPolygonBorders(polygonBorderCheckbox.isSelected());
            }
        });
        //...
    } 
}
```

Class `VisualizationPanel`, method `recalculate()` creates a new `VisualizationThread` that generates the `BufferedImage` in question using the properties in `VisualizationPanel`. When recalculate is finisehd,

```
public class VisualizationPanel extends JPanel {

   private boolean polygonBorders;
   //here be more property class variables and getter/setter for them

    public void setPolygonBorders(boolean polygonBorders) {
        this.polygonBorders = polygonBorders;
        recalculate();
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }

    public void recalculate(){
        vt = new VisualizationThread(this);
        vt.execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        dataTransformation.setToScale(transform_factor, transform_factor);
        g2d.transform(dataTransformation);
        g2d.drawImage(toDraw, 0, 0, null);
        this.setSize((int) Math.ceil(transform_factor * maxwidth), (int) Math.ceil(transform_factor * maxheight));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) Math.ceil(transform_factor * maxwidth), (int) Math.ceil(transform_factor * maxheight)));
        this.revalidate();
        hx.modifyVisPanelViewport(this);
    }
}
```

`VisualizationThread` takes a `VisualizationPanel`, reads its properties and calculates a new `BufferedImage based on that. When done,` done()`is called, which then sets the new`BufferedImage`to draw to the`VisualizationPanel` and repaints it.

```
public class VisualizationThread extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {
    private VisualizationPanel vp;
    private BufferedImage toDraw;
    
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
    // The bufferedImage  gets drawn on here.
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        vp.setToDraw(toDraw);
        vp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(toDraw.getWidth(), toDraw.getHeight()));
        vp.repaint();
        vp.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code, without that we don't really have the information we need to help

Comment: Are you using `AffineTransformOp`?

Comment: dataTransformation is java.awt.geom.AffineTransform, so I am not using AffineTransformOp. I added some code, I hope you can understand better now!

Comment: @jurib: Use `@` to address people in comments; I saw your update only by accident.

Answer (score 2):

It *looks* like the host peer component is expecting to render an image with one color model but encountering another. There are just too many ways for this to go wrong for a definitive answer, but several things bear closer scrutiny:

- Verify that your `BufferedImage` has a compatible color model and space, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).
- Consider scaling with `AffineTransformOp`, outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4216635/230513), as it can create a "destination image with the correct size and number of bands."
- While `done()` is executed on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), verify that the rest of your program is correctly synchronized, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44981400/230513).