# BufferedImage getScaledInstance changes brightness of picture

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, brightness

I use this piece of code to draw a Image into a Graphics component. It should size the image to the maximum space available, if it is big enough:

```
    // getWidth() = component width, image.getWidth() = image width
    double w = getWidth() * 1.0 / image.getWidth();
    double h = getHeight() * 1.0 / image.getHeight();
    if (w < 1 || h < 1) {
        double d = Math.min(Math.min(w, h), 1);
        g.drawImage(bi.getScaledInstance((int) (d * image.getWidth()), (int) (d * image.getHeight()), Image.SCALE_REPLICATE), 0, 0, null);
    } else {
        g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
    }
```

The code works, the image gets scaled correctly. But unfortunately when the image is scaled, the brightness of the images changes as well on the Graphics!

Has anyone an idea where this could come from?
I attached the scaled (first) and the not scaled version of the screen.

I hope someone can help me with that!

Cheers!
Sebastian

[image: image scaled with <code>getScaledInstance</code>]
[image: without <code>getScaledInstance</code>]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with `Image.getScaledInstance` (and may also be related to gray scaled images).  I tried several other hints but had the same result.

Instead, I employed my own scaling algorithm (which I stole from the Internet), which uses a divide and conquer approach, which generally produces better results...

So, original ontop, `Image#getScaledInstance` on the left, custom scaled on the right

[image]

nb: This uses some of my own personal library code, so it might not be entirely suitable for you, but this presents the basics...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ImageScaleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ImageScaleTest();
    }

    public ImageScaleTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static enum RenderQuality {

        High,
        Medium,
        Low
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage original;
        private BufferedImage scaled2;
        private Image scaled;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                original = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/image"));
                scaled = original.getScaledInstance(original.getWidth() / 2, original.getHeight() / 2, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
                scaled2 = getScaledInstance(original, 0.5d, RenderQuality.High);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 600);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(original, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.drawImage(scaled, 0, original.getHeight(), this);
            g2d.drawImage(scaled2, scaled.getWidth(this), original.getHeight(), this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static BufferedImage getScaledInstance(BufferedImage img, double dScaleFactor, RenderQuality quality) {

        BufferedImage imgBuffer = null;

        if (quality == RenderQuality.High) {

//            System.out.println("Scale high quality...");
            imgBuffer = getScaledInstance(img, dScaleFactor, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR, true);

        } else if (quality == RenderQuality.Medium) {

            imgBuffer = getScaledInstance(img, dScaleFactor, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR, false);

        } else {

//            System.out.println("Scale low quality...");
            imgBuffer = getScaledInstance(img, dScaleFactor, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR, false);

        }

        return imgBuffer;

    }

    protected static BufferedImage getScaledInstance(BufferedImage img, double dScaleFactor, Object hint, boolean bHighQuality) {

        BufferedImage imgScale = img;

        int iImageWidth = (int) Math.round(img.getWidth() * dScaleFactor);
        int iImageHeight = (int) Math.round(img.getHeight() * dScaleFactor);

        if (dScaleFactor <= 1.0d) {

            imgScale = getScaledDownInstance(img, iImageWidth, iImageHeight, hint, bHighQuality);

        } else {

            imgScale = getScaledUpInstance(img, iImageWidth, iImageHeight, hint, bHighQuality);

        }

        return imgScale;

    }

    protected static BufferedImage getScaledDownInstance(BufferedImage img,
            int targetWidth,
            int targetHeight,
            Object hint,
            boolean higherQuality) {

        int type = (img.getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE)
                ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

        BufferedImage ret = (BufferedImage) img;

        if (targetHeight > 0 || targetWidth > 0) {
            int w, h;
            if (higherQuality) {
                // Use multi-step technique: start with original size, then
                // scale down in multiple passes with drawImage()
                // until the target size is reached
                w = img.getWidth();
                h = img.getHeight();
            } else {
                // Use one-step technique: scale directly from original
                // size to target size with a single drawImage() call
                w = targetWidth;
                h = targetHeight;
            }

            do {
                if (higherQuality && w > targetWidth) {
                    w /= 2;
                    if (w < targetWidth) {
                        w = targetWidth;
                    }
                }

                if (higherQuality && h > targetHeight) {
                    h /= 2;
                    if (h < targetHeight) {
                        h = targetHeight;
                    }
                }

                BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(Math.max(w, 1), Math.max(h, 1), type);
                Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, hint);
                g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, h, null);
                g2.dispose();

                ret = tmp;
            } while (w != targetWidth || h != targetHeight);
        } else {
            ret = new BufferedImage(1, 1, type);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    protected static BufferedImage getScaledUpInstance(BufferedImage img,
            int targetWidth,
            int targetHeight,
            Object hint,
            boolean higherQuality) {

        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

        BufferedImage ret = (BufferedImage) img;
        int w, h;
        if (higherQuality) {
            // Use multi-step technique: start with original size, then
            // scale down in multiple passes with drawImage()
            // until the target size is reached
            w = img.getWidth();
            h = img.getHeight();
        } else {
            // Use one-step technique: scale directly from original
            // size to target size with a single drawImage() call
            w = targetWidth;
            h = targetHeight;
        }

        do {
            if (higherQuality && w < targetWidth) {
                w *= 2;
                if (w > targetWidth) {
                    w = targetWidth;
                }
            }

            if (higherQuality && h < targetHeight) {
                h *= 2;
                if (h > targetHeight) {
                    h = targetHeight;
                }
            }

            BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
            Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, hint);
            g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, h, null);
            g2.dispose();

            ret = tmp;
            tmp = null;
        } while (w != targetWidth || h != targetHeight);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

May, also, like to take a look at [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://web.archive.org/web/20130119065536/http://today.java.net:80/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

ps- I did a quick bit of searching and this seems to be a bug (or feature) in the API

Comment: +1 for the perils; `AffineTransformOp`, outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4216635/230513), is an alternative.

Comment: Thanks! I will use this implementation!