# Java: Slow image scale

Tags: java, webserver, raspberry-pi, image-scaling, image-size

Im using this code in java:

```
    Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("imagepath/file.png").getScaledInstance(300, 300,        BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);

    BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.SCALE_FAST);
    buffered.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0 , null);

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(buffered, "png", os); 
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
    return in;
```

This successfully scales down and shows a thumbnail in the browser using my laptop. However when I'm launch it on my mini server (Raspberry Pi) it is horrible slow. More accurate is about 4 times longer than loading the actual full-res image.

Can anybody tell me how this is even possible? 300x300 < 1280x720! Should be less work and less bandwidth!

Cheers!

Comment: are you saving the resized image somewhere? If not, you're basically redoing the resizing operation EVERY time the image is requested. and note that a 1280x720 .jpg image requires ~2.7 meg of ram to store in raw bitmap format in memory. a Pi is not exactly a speed-demon of a system.

Comment: Because the Raspberry Pi has a much slower processor than your laptop, and resizing the image is a processor-intensive operation.

Comment: @MarcB Wow 2.7MB!? Is it really that bad :S Is there any way to do it more seamless into a stream or is caching the way to go?

Comment: 1280x720 = 921,600 pixels. 24bit image = 3 bytes/pixel, so 921,600 * 3 = ~2.65meg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getScaledInstance is known to be slow, see for example [this article](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) for a detailed explanation.

Note that your

```
BufferedImage buffered = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.SCALE_FAST);
```

line is wrong, here for the third argument you should specify the image type ( TYPE_INT_RGB, TYPE_INT_ARGB, TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE etc) and not SCALE_FAST (which is not even a field in BufferedImage)

Also see this: [How to scale a BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage)

For quality downscaling see this: [Quality of Image after resize very low -- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java)

Comment: Thank you! Weird that the code worked before and didn't crash. guess that it used some default value because the one I sent in was completely wrong.

Comment: Fyi- one step scaling generally doesn't produce a nice result (especially over a large range), typically better to use a stepped approach, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, and this is actually also discussed in detail in the "The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()" article (in the "On-the-Fly Scaling" part), but for completeness I also included your link in the answer