# How to obtain a resized BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Say I have 2 `TIF` images and I read one of them into a `BufferedImage` instance:

```
ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("tif").next();
reader.setInput(inputStream, false);   // inputStream is the first image.
BufferedImage bufferedImage = reader.read(0);
```

Now I want to create a new `BufferedImage` *without reading the other image*. It should be the same as the previous one, but only different in size. `imageType` seems to be 0 for `TIF` images, but the following doesn't work.

```
BufferedImage largeBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, 0);
```

Is there any way to clone the existing `BufferedImage` and only change its size?

BTW I want to be able to do it for any image format. I don't want to deal with details like `imageType` if possible.

Comment: *but the following doesn't work.* -- why not? What's the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scale a BufferedImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage)

Comment: @Thomas It doesn't accept '0' as a valid `imageType` for `tif` images.

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedImage deepCopy(BufferedImage bi)/*method to clone BufferedImage*/ {
   ColorModel cm = bi.getColorModel();
   boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
   WritableRaster raster = bi.copyData(null);
   return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
}
BufferedImage newImg = deepCopy(oldImg);//clone it
Graphics2D g = newImg.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(newImg, 0, 0, width, height, null);//newImg will be resized
```

Comment: Won't it change my original `bufferedImage`? I don't want to change it, I want to copy it.

Comment: I couldn't understand the difference between `bufferedImage` and `originalImage`. If they are the same thing, it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I made few mistakes. I fixed all of it.

Comment: nearly all - just a missing bracket in your first line (it has moved into the comment ^^)

Comment: @Jeremy That didn't exactly work, but I found a solution using some of your code. So I upvoted your answer :)
The problem is you have to change the raster to resize the image. `drawImage()` won't do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

When you draw in your `paint` method, you can add more parameters to stretch and scale image, see `g.drawImage` at this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)).

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found a working solution for my problem.

```
private BufferedImage copyAndResize(BufferedImage source, int width, int height)
{
    ColorModel cm = source.getColorModel();
    boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    WritableRaster raster = source.copyData(null);
    SampleModel sm = raster.getSampleModel().createCompatibleSampleModel(width, height);
    WritableRaster newRaster = WritableRaster.createWritableRaster(sm, null);
    BufferedImage newBi = new BufferedImage(cm, newRaster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
    return newBi;
}
```

Comment: This is far more complicated than what you actually need. Take a look at the following article which describes several options:  https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html

Comment: @BrettOkken Why is my code complicated? You should know that I just want to get a `BufferedImage` instance to write a new image. I don't care about its content/quality at all, I only care about its size and properties.