# How to load a image into JEditorPane using HTMLEditorKit while resizing it smoothly?

Tags: java, image, swing, htmleditorkit

I wrote codes that loads images into `JEditorPane` using `HTMLEditorKit`. I know how to resize the image using HTML. But the problem is the loaded image losses quality. I am trying to find ways to resize without losing quality.

Comment: Maybe like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4216635/230513)?

Comment: Well , I use insertHTML() method of htmlEditorKit  . I need the image that JEditorPane shows , so that I can resize it. But I can't find how.

Comment: load the image into BufferedImage and then resize as said in the linkby trashgod then put it to your htmlEditorkit

Comment: *"I know how to resize the image using HTML."*  Do you know how to resize an image smoothly using pure Java code?  If not, see the advice of @trashgod.  Once you've sorted that out, you'll need to extend the `HTMLEditorKit` and override the `public View create(Element element) ` method of the `HTMLFactory` to use the new functionality (based on what I was just looking at in an old project that added support for the `applet` element).

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Thompson suggested ,

extend the `HTMLEditorKit` and override `public View create(Element element)`
of `HTMLFactory` .

extend from `ImageView` and override the `public void paint(Graphics g, Shape a)` method. Get the image and resize it.

```
getScaledInstance(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING)
```

with your favourite scaling `HINT` and finally draw.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on the exact use-case the OP is after, but I've used the following simpler alternative for an HTML help viewer – override the `paint()` method of the `JEditorPane` to set a rendering hint:

```java
        JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane() {
            @Override public void paint(Graphics g) {
                if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
                    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                                        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
                    super.paint(g2);
                    g2.dispose();
                } else {
                    // Print and other non-Graphics2D contexts.
                    super.paint(g);
                }
            }
        };
```

This provides nice and easy improvement with non-integral scaling factor hidpi screens, for example.  The quality would still be suboptimal if an image is [scaled more than half down](https://web.archive.org/web/20080516181120/http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) of the original.  For that use-case a custom `HTMLEditorKit` / `HTMLVactory` producing a custom `ImageView` would be necessary, as others have pointed out.