# I can't seem to downscale pixelart to single pixels without antialiasing

Tags: java, image-processing

I am trying to downscale an pixelart image (of the game stardew valley)  consisting of 4x4 pixels per block of the same color to the same image with 1x1 pixel per block.

Photoshop is doing a great job when I just resize it with the `NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR` interpolation.

But when I use the technique from: [How to scale a BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage)
but with `TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR` instead it gets all destorted.

What is going wrong and how should I go about fixing it?

```
            BufferedImage old = getScreenShot();
            int w = old.getWidth();
            int h = old.getHeight();

            int newWidth = w/4;
            int newHeight = h/4;


            BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, old.getType());
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.scale(0.25, 0.25);
            AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
            resized = scaleOp.filter(old, resized);

            //TODO (remove)  for debugging the screencapture capability
            File outputfile = new File("C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/imagetestmap/test.jpg");
            try {
                ImageIO.write(resized, "jpg", outputfile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return resized;
```

actual screenshot:

[image: actual screenshot]

what photoshop sees:

[image: what photoshop sees]

what my program sees:

[image: what my program sees]

Comment: Kind of funny that your program sees a different image altogether. The character is facing a different way. Cool program!!! :)

Comment: Anyway, I think you are dealing with JPEG compression artifacts.

Comment: sorry bout that, i lost the original screenshot as i was just experimenting, but shouldnt there be a way to shrink it whitout artifacts?

Comment: Write it out as PNG, you won't have artifacts.

Comment: This worked like a charm! you are amazing, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cris Luengo found the solution, I should have used .png instead of jpg.

This is the working code:

```
            BufferedImage old = getScreenShot();
            int w = old.getWidth();
            int h = old.getHeight();

            int newWidth = w/4;
            int newHeight = h/4;


            BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

             AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.scale(0.25, 0.25);
            AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
            resized = scaleOp.filter(old, resized);

            //TODO (remove)  for debugging the screencapture capability
            File outputfile = new File("C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/imagetestmap/test.png");
            try {
                ImageIO.write(resized, "png", outputfile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```